# Editing JQuery function to affect 2 IDs instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 5 tablist on my webpage and it has some custom code that allows for clicking of left/right arrows to change tabs. If I want to add a second bootstrap 5 tablist with a new ID, how can I edit my code to include the new ID and affect that tablist as well?

**Expected result**: Each tablist has their own arrows above it that affect only the tablist below it to switch tabs next/previous when clicked.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="tab-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-12 title-text variation-one mb-3 mb-lg-0 ps-4">
                <h2>Learning Products</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 tab-container-arrows text-end pe-4">
                <a class="d-inline-block me-2" id="previous">
                    <img src="/assets/images/icons/left-arrow.svg" alt="Right Arrow" class="left-arrow">
                </a>
                <a class="d-inline-block ms-2" id="next">
                    <img src="/assets/images/icons/right-arrow.svg" alt="Left Arrow" class="left-arrow">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="learningTabs" aria-owns="software-tab courses-tab accessories-tab popular-tab">
            <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="software-tab" data-index="1" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#software">Shop Software</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
                <a class="nav-link" id="courses-tab" data-index="2" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#courses">Shop Courses</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
                <a class="nav-link" id="accessories-tab" data-index="3" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#prep">Shop Accessories</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
                <a class="nav-link" id="popular-tab" data-index="4" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#popular">Shop Popular Items</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="software">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <div class="text-pill">
                                <span>Shop Software</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
                        <h3>What do you want to learn today?</h3>
                        <p>Buy or rent textbooks, learn new subjects and skills on your own, or get the materials to prep for tests and certifications. Our books cover a wide range of topics, from accounting to world languages.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="courses">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <div class="text-pill">
                                <span>Shop courses</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
                        <h3>Improve student outcomes and classroom learning.</h3>
                        <p>Buy our courses with learning technology you need to increase confidence in your classroom. Teaching and learning made easy. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="accessories">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <div class="text-pill">
                                <span>Shop Accessories</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
                        <h3>Review courses to help pass your next test.</h3>
                        <p>Get the materials you need to prep for tests and certifications. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="popular">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <div class="text-pill">
                                <span>Shop Imprints</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
                        <h3>Learn something new.</h3>
                        <p>Buy our popular items to help you learn a new skill or get training material. Our brands and imprints cover a wide range of titles.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var learningTabs = $("#learningTabs");
var currentActive, NextID, PreviousID;
$('#next').on('click', function(event) {
    currentActive = $("#learningTabs li > a.active");
    NextID = Math.min((parseInt($(currentActive).attr('data-index')) + 1), $("#learningTabs li").length);
    if (NextID !== parseInt($(currentActive).attr('data-index'))) {
        $(learningTabs).find("li a[data-index='" + NextID + "']")[0].click();
    }
});

$('#previous').on('click', function(event) {
    currentActive = $("#learningTabs li > a.active");
    PreviousID = Math.max((parseInt($(currentActive).attr('data-index')) - 1), 1);
    if (PreviousID !== parseInt($(currentActive).attr('data-index'))) {
        $(learningTabs).find("li a[data-index='" + PreviousID + "']")[0].click();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I would suggest you switch to using Class instead of ID for the various elements. This way you can have a parent element with a single ID and then identify specific buttons that are children of that ID.

Comment: [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10) say each id can belong to only one element.

Comment: `$('#next')` will get the FIRST element with that ID. You can have a thousand... jQuery does not care. So you have to make you code CLEARLY target one element. -- POST the HTML.. There is a way for sure.

Comment: if next, previous is in learningTabs, you can do `learningTabs.find('#next').on..`, though you should always use classes if you have multiple items (which is almost always)

Comment: The question is... Multiple ID are used on other elements too? -- Probalbly. -- Post the HTML to get accurate advises.

Comment: If I use a class for those buttons, won't it automatically switch tabs on both sections when the user clicks one? For example learningTabs and sellingTabs are both affected by the .next and .previous button classes.

Comment: Posted the HTML @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Where ever are some IDs within `tab-container`... If that container is to be repeated, you have to change the IDs for classes for every child below.

Comment: That tab-container will not be repeated, a new one will be created with unique IDs/classes for child elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea about jQuery DOM traversing is always about starting from the click target... To find the closest relevant parent which wuold be the *"root"* of a pattern and in which to find the elements we want for this chunck of a pattern.

Have a close look at the click handlers.

In DOM tranversing, we usually work with classes (Or using attribute selectors, with types, attributes like name, aria-x, data-x, etc.), but nerver with IDs... Which are for UNIQUE elements. And unique is not something that can be acounted in a DOM structure pattern "repeated".

Have a look at that ugly looking demo (because I feel lazy today about CSS). It is supposed to behave as you wish.

```js
console.clear()

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".next").on("click", function (event) {
    
    let nav = $(this).closest(".tab-container").find(".nav")
    let nav_links = nav.find(".nav-link");
    let link_count = nav_links.length;
    let navLink_active_index = nav.find(".nav-link.active").parent().index();
    
    nav_links.eq( (navLink_active_index + 1) % link_count )[0].click()
  });

  $(".previous").on("click", function (event) {
    let nav = $(this).closest(".tab-container").find(".nav")
    let nav_links = nav.find(".nav-link");
    let link_count = nav_links.length;
    let navLink_active_index = nav.find(".nav-link.active").parent().index();
    
    nav_links.eq( (navLink_active_index - 1) % link_count )[0].click()
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="tab-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-12 title-text variation-one mb-3 mb-lg-0 ps-4">
        <h2>Learning Products</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 tab-container-arrows text-end pe-4">
        <a class="d-inline-block me-2 previous">
          <img src="/2022-assets/images/icons/left-arrow.svg" alt="Right Arrow" class="left-arrow">
        </a>
        <a class="d-inline-block ms-2 next">
          <img src="/2022-assets/images/icons/right-arrow.svg" alt="Left Arrow" class="left-arrow">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" class="learningTabs" aria-owns="software-tab courses-tab accessories-tab popular-tab">
      <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="software-tab" data-index="1" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#software">Shop Software</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
        <a class="nav-link" id="courses-tab" data-index="2" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#courses">Shop Courses</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
        <a class="nav-link" id="accessories-tab" data-index="3" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#prep">Shop Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
        <a class="nav-link" id="popular-tab" data-index="4" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#popular">Shop Popular Items</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="software">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <div class="text-pill">
                <span>Shop Software</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <h3>What do you want to learn today?</h3>
            <p>Buy or rent textbooks, learn new subjects and skills on your own, or get the materials to prep for tests and certifications. Our books cover a wide range of topics, from accounting to world languages.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="courses">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <div class="text-pill">
                <span>Shop courses</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <h3>Improve student outcomes and classroom learning.</h3>
            <p>Buy our courses with learning technology you need to increase confidence in your classroom. Teaching and learning made easy. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="accessories">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <div class="text-pill">
                <span>Shop Accessories</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <h3>Review courses to help pass your next test.</h3>
            <p>Get the materials you need to prep for tests and certifications. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="popular">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <div class="text-pill">
                <span>Shop Imprints</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <h3>Learn something new.</h3>
            <p>Buy our popular items to help you learn a new skill or get training material. Our brands and imprints cover a wide range of titles.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="tab-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-12 title-text variation-one mb-3 mb-lg-0 ps-4">
        <h2>Some other Products</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 tab-container-arrows text-end pe-4">
        <a class="d-inline-block me-2 previous">
          <img src="/2022-assets/images/icons/left-arrow.svg" alt="Right Arrow" class="left-arrow">
        </a>
        <a class="d-inline-block ms-2 next">
          <img src="/2022-assets/images/icons/right-arrow.svg" alt="Left Arrow" class="left-arrow">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" class="learningTabs" aria-owns="software-tab courses-tab accessories-tab popular-tab">
      <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="software-tab" data-index="1" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#software_UNIQUEID">Shop Software</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
        <a class="nav-link" id="courses-tab" data-index="2" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#courses_UNIQUEID">Shop Courses</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
        <a class="nav-link" id="accessories-tab" data-index="3" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#prep_UNIQUEID">Shop Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="tab">
        <a class="nav-link" id="popular-tab" data-index="4" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#popular_UNIQUEID">Shop Popular Items</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="software_UNIQUEID">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <div class="text-pill">
                <span>Shop Software</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <h3>What do you want to learn today?</h3>
            <p>Buy or rent textbooks, learn new subjects and skills on your own, or get the materials to prep for tests and certifications. Our books cover a wide range of topics, from accounting to world languages.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="courses_UNIQUEID">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <div class="text-pill">
                <span>Shop courses</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <h3>Improve student outcomes and classroom learning.</h3>
            <p>Buy our courses with learning technology you need to increase confidence in your classroom. Teaching and learning made easy. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="accessories_UNIQUEID">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <div class="text-pill">
                <span>Shop Accessories</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <h3>Review courses to help pass your next test.</h3>
            <p>Get the materials you need to prep for tests and certifications. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="popular_UNIQUEID">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <div class="text-pill">
                <span>Shop Imprints</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <h3>Learn something new.</h3>
            <p>Buy our popular items to help you learn a new skill or get training material. Our brands and imprints cover a wide range of titles.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```